# Kafka Server daemon to be launched on every broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have 3 node Zookeeper cluster and a 10 node Kafka cluster. After launching Zookeeper daemon on 3 nodes, I then proceed to launch Kafka daemon by using the command

```
./kafka-server-start.sh "config/server.properties"
```

And my `server.properties` is correctly configured containing the proper Zookeeper connection string eg:

```
zookeeper.connect=192.168.140.23:2181,192.168.140.24:2181,192.168.140.25:2181
```

My question is do I need to start the Kafka daemon on all of the 10 broker nodes using `./kafka-server-start.sh "config/server.properties"` or starting it on just one of them will suffice ?

For reference:

**producers.properties**

```
metadata.broker.list=192.168.140.23:9092,192.168.140.24:9092,192.168.140.25:9092,192.168.140.26:9092,192.168.140.27:9092,192.168.140.11:9092,192.168.140.12:9092,192.168.140.13:9092,192.168.140.14:9092
```

**consumer.properties**

```
zookeeper.connect=192.168.140.23:2181,192.168.140.24:2181,192.168.140.25:2181
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start all the Kafka servers on those 10 nodes by issuing "./kafka-server-start.sh ...". An automatic tool might be a good way to do this.

Comment: You should also specify unique `broker.id` for each server.